# i Am getting error at var sse12; like implicitly local type variables must be initialized

Tags: c#, web-services

hi i Am getting error at var sse12; like implicitly local type variables must be initialized please suggest me actually here data coming web service

and the code is

```
private static void eCom4(DataServiceQuery<VEmployee4> vv, int sno)
    {
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        Console.WriteLine("processing 4...");
        string strEmp = string.Empty;
        string strFileNmae = "DSEmp_v4_20180607_Pipe";
        strEmp = "Source|Sno|FirstName|MiddleName|LastName |Email|EmployeeNo|CompanyCode|CompanyId|CompanyName|ADUsername|BusinessUnit|EmployeeNo|Title|FirstName|LastName|MiddleName|ADUsername|Email|DateOfBirth|Gender|PhoneNo|Nationality|MaritalStatus|Address|BusinessUnit|CostCenterCode|CompanyCode|CompanyId|CompanyName|DivisionId|DivisionName|DepartmentId|DepartmentName";
        writetxt(strFileNmae, strEmp);
        string strEmpCol = string.Empty;
        var compID = new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 16, 19, 20, 21, 81, 90, 126, 391, 436, 451, 499, 501, 502, 503, 505 };
        //var compID = new int[] { 1, 2};
        for (int i = 0; i < compID.Length; i++)
        {
            int temp = compID[i];
            //string temp1 = Convert.ToString(compID[i]);                            
            var sse12;

            if (temp == 1)
            {

                sse12 = from sse1 in vv
                        where sse1.CompanyId == temp && sse1.DivisionId == 1021159
                        select sse1;
                //foreach (var item in sse12)
                //{
                //    strEmp = sno.ToString() + "|" + veCount.ToString() + "|" + item.FirstName + "|" + item.MiddleName + "|" + item.LastName + "|" + item.Email + "|" + item.EmployeeNo + "|" + item.CompanyCode + "|" + item.CompanyId + "|" + item.CompanyName + "|" + item.ADUsername + "|" + item.BusinessUnit + "|" + item.EmployeeNo + "|" + item.Title + "|" + item.FirstName + "|" + item.LastName + "|" + item.MiddleName + "|" + item.ADUsername + "|" + item.Email + "|" + item.DateOfBirth + "|" + item.Gender + "|" + item.PhoneNo + "|" + item.Nationality + "|" + item.MaritalStatus + "|" + item.Address + "|" + item.BusinessUnit + "|" + item.CostCenterCode + "|" + item.CompanyCode + "|" + item.CompanyId + "|" + item.CompanyName + "|" + item.DivisionId + "|" + item.DivisionName + "|" + item.DepartmentId + "|" + item.DepartmentName;
                //    Console.WriteLine("First Name ={0} && Comapny Id = {1}", item.FirstName, item.CompanyCode);
                //    writetxt(strFileNmae, strEmp);
                //}
            }
            else
            {

                sse12 = from sse1 in vv
                        where sse1.CompanyId == temp
                        select sse1;
```

}
}

Answer (score 3):

In C#, the `var` keyword is used to let the compiler determine the type of a variable during compilation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

You cannot declare a variable with the `var` keyword without initializing it and must specify its type:

```
VEmployee4 sse12;
```

Comment: hi its ok but iam getting one more error at WHERE key word like